# APEX_JSON.PARSE. How to deal horrible json

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a huge json in clob like

```
{"response":"{\"atr1\":1.0,\"atr2\":2.0,\"atr3\":3.0};"}
```

Attributes over 9000.

I want to parse in with apex_json:

```
declare 
  lgk varchar2(50);
begin
   apex_json.parse(i);
    lgk := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'response');
    dbms_output.put_line(lgk);
end;
```

In  output i can see something like

```
{"atr1":1.0,"atr2":2.0,"atr3":3.0};
```

If I try to parse this again, I will get an error: Unexpected character ";".
How i can validate json and replace items like ";" using apex? I rly don't want parse clob into varchar2 and replace what I need.

Answer (score 0):

First, Your `response` value (i.e: `"{\"atr1\":1.0,\"atr2\":2.0,\"atr3\":3.0};"`) is not a valid json object. It is just a string value. Remove the double quotes, and the forward slashes and validate, you'll get the following:

```
{"atr1":1.0,"atr2":2.0,"atr3":3.0};
```

You can validate it online [here](http://jsonlint.com/), and you'll get error because of `;`

Hence, the correct format of the JSON should be as follows:

```
{"response":"{"atr1":1.0,"atr2":2.0,"atr3":3.0}}
```

Second, you do not need to parse twice, you parse once, and then you fetch any values you need depending on the path parameter you pass. For example, here is your code after modification:

```
declare 
  json_clob clob := '{"response":{"atr1":1.0,"atr2":2.0,"atr3":3.0}}';
  lgk varchar2(50);
begin
    apex_json.parse(json_clob);
    lgk := apex_json.get_number(p_path => 'response.atr1');
    dbms_output.put_line(lgk);
end;
/

--output:
--1
```